# Phrase Rephraser

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm writing a bot and instead of phrasing user facing communication the same way, I want to implement a certain degree of change in the language, while still maintaining the original intent. To do this, instead of a standard dictionary key-value pairs, such as

`user_response ["GREET"] = "Hello, how are you?"`

is currently replaced such:

`user_response ["GREET"] = ["Hello, how are you?", "What's up?", "Hi, all good today?"]`

and a random string is picked from the choices available.
The problem is, it'll take much too long to do this manually, for all the strings in the system.

**Question: Is there a way NLTK or other library can rephrase a given phrase?**
*There is a question from 2010 that is similar in intent, but didn't have much by way of responses or follow ups.*

Answer (score 0):

NLTK won't help with generating rephrasing - you can use a natural language generation model like GPT-2 but that will require lot of time and compute resources and may not even deliver what you are looking for. Your best bet would be to use a "parapharsing" app. Even that will require manual entry of initial sentence to generate the rewrites. You may be able to find a paraphrasing API but I am not aware of one.